# System.IO.FileNotFoundException Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' or one of its dependencies.

while running the Xamarin iOS project I am getting the above exception.

If you can help me out it would be much appreciated.

[References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxiqH.jpg)

Comment: why does your iOS project have a reference to Android?

Comment: it does not, I have tried to remove all the Android references from the project but the exception still does not go away, meanwhile, I have updated the description of my question with the screenshot of my Xamarin.iOS project references. kindly have a look.

Comment: Are you sure your startup project is iOS, not an android?

Comment: Yes Srusti, my startup project is iOS.

Comment: Perhaps your shared-code project (Appnewpdf) contains a reference to Android. Eliminate that reference. If it won't build after doing so, then you have some Android code there, that needs to be moved to your Android project.

Comment: I have cleared all those references and I don't even have my Android project loaded as I just need to run the iOS project only.

Comment: Please try Delete bin and obj and rebuild again.

Comment: I have tried that as well, but still no luck.

Comment: Looks like  your iOS project is referencing to some other project, which is referencing Xamarin.Android so causes the error.Please check it.